# how to remove spacing between ActionBar icons

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Once again I'm fighting with `ActionBar` styles for SDK 14 and above. I'm trying to remove/reduce spacing between `Tab` icons since the default spacing does not fit well in my design. Currently my style looks like:

```
       <style name="sMain" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/mTabAreaBackground</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="mTabAreaBackground" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">#2b2f33</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <!-- below attributes have no effect -->
    <item name="android:width">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:height">0dp</item>
</style>
```

I "removed" the active Tab indicator by making it transparent since my Tab icons already have one. I assumed that the spacing between Tab icons was somehow related to the Tab indicator, which was still there though I made it transparent. Therefore I tried to apply a width and height of 0 in the same style (inherited from `style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView`). I don't know if my assumption was incorrect or I'm doing something wrong, I also could not find any documentation/examples related to adjusting spacing between Tab icons.

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, the spacing is because of the `padding` on the `TabView`.
You should changing the padding on the `TabView` something like below.

```
<style name="ActionBarTabStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>

    <item name="android:paddingLeft">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">2dp</item>
</style>
```

The default padding on the `TabView` seems to be 16dp.

Comment: it's a shame I haven't thought of it >< Thanks, this works fine

Comment: If you open `res/values/styles.xml` in the android source code and do a quick scan for `<style name="Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView" parent="Widget.ActionBar.TabView">` you will see that its 16dp.

Comment: I'm trying same but not working in my case please suggest