# Android Action Bar Tab's width is too wide

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have an action bar loaded with couples tab

ActionBar.Tab tab;
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

```
    // Hide Actionbar Icon
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

    // Hide Actionbar Title
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    // Create Actionbar Tabs
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create Contact Tab
    tab = actionBar.newTab().setTabListener(new ContactActivity());
    // Create your own custom icon
    tab.setIcon(R.drawable.contact_tab);
    //tab.setText("Contact");
    actionBar.addTab(tab);
```

And this is "style.xml" that apply the theme for the action bar...

```
<style name="customTabStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:showDividers">none</item>
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/bottomtab</item>
</style>
```

Everything was normal before i set the background image to the action bar. But after i set a background image to it, the tab size become wide and i can't reduce the size..

Before adding background Image
[image: This is before adding background image]

After adding background Image

[image]

Comment: See my answer here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392390/how-to-remove-spacing-between-actionbar-icons/18392474#18392474

Comment: Hi Varun, I've tried the left padding and right padding but i still get the result in second image that i attached above. But thanks anyway, let me know if you have any idea what is going on.

Comment: what is the background you are adding. Seems to me that there is a problem with the background.

Comment: it's a 480x74 png , is there any problem with the image?

Comment: The image just seems to be too wide for a tab. You might consider using a color or a solid or a gradient drawable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The action bar tab has a build in padding of 16 dip for left and right.

`<style name="Widget.AppCompat.Base.ActionBar.TabView" parent="">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/abc_tab_indicator_ab_holo</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dip</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">16dip</item>
        <item name="android:minWidth">80dip</item>
    </style>`

In order to override the padding you need to override those properties:

```
<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.MY_STYLE" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_MY_STYLE_light</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">1dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">1dip</item>
```

This fixed the problem to me.

Comment: Thank you, although it's an old question.